# If $M \ne N^2$ is $\det(M-N^2)\ne 0$?

Tags: matrices

Does $M \ne N^2$ imply that $\det(M-N^2)\ne 0$?

I believe it's correct because: $M- N^2 \ne O$ where O is null matrix and after taking determinant on both sides we get $\det(M-N^2) \ne 0 $ but I am not sure if taking determinant on both sides of equation is allowed.

Comment: The determinant of a nonzero matrix certainly may be zero.

Comment: Two different matrices can have the same determinant.

Comment: This implication would be equivalent to its contrapositive: $\det(M-N^2)=0\implies M-N^2=O$ which is certainly not true.

Comment: So taking determinant on two sides of a matrix equation is not allowed @SeanRoberson , LordSharktheUnkown ?

Comment: You can certainly take the determinant of both sides of an equation. But $M- N^2 \ne O$ is  not an equation!

Comment: But non-equations are not equations: $-1=1$ does not imply $(-1)^2=1^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, take $M$ as the zero matrix and $N = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then the determinant of $M - N^2$ is zero, even though $N^2 = N \neq M$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $N$, and let $A$ be any non-invertible matrix. Choose $M$ so that $A=M-N^2.$ Then, $A$ is non-zero, but its determinant is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take the determinant on both sides of $A \neq B$. You are basically saying here that if $A \neq 0$ then $\det(A)\neq 0$ which is wrong ! Take for example a singular matrix $A$.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to look at $M\neq N^2$ as the negation of $M=N^2$.

With this in mind, suppose $M=N^2$. You want to show that $M=N^2\iff \det(M-N^2)=0$.

Obviously, if $M=N^2$, then $(M-N^2)_{i,j}=0$ for all valid indices $i$ and $j$. Thus, $M=N^2\implies\det(M-N^2)=0$.

By negating the above proposition, you have $\det(M-N^2)\neq 0\implies M\neq N^2$. However, you need to still need to show that $M=N^2\impliedby \det(M-N^2)=0$.

Suppose $\det(M-N^2)=0$. Without loss of generality, let $M-N^2=\left(\begin{matrix}1&1\\1&1\end{matrix}\right)$. The determinant of $M-N^2$ is $0$, however $M\neq N^2$. So $M=N^2\impliedby \det(M-N^2)=0$ is *not* true.

From this, you may conclude that $M\neq N^2\implies\det(M-N^2)\neq 0$ is false.

---

In summary:

$$M=N^2\implies\det(M-N^2)=0$$

...thus...

$$\det(M-n^2)\neq0\implies M\neq N^2$$

and

$$\det(M-N^2)=0\not\implies M=N^2$$

...thus...

$$M\neq N^2\not\implies\det(M-N^2)=0$$